# How can I navigate to the next page through Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script that scrapes information from a large travel agency. My code closely follows the tutorial at https://python.gotrained.com/selenium-scraping-booking-com/.

However, I would like to be able to navigate to the next page as I'm now limited to `n_results = 25`. Where do I add this in the code? I know that I can target the pagination button with `driver.find_element_by_class_name('paging-next').click()`, but I don't know where to incorporate it.

I have tried to put it in the `for` loop within the `scrape_results` function, which I have copied below. However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
def scrape_results(driver, n_results):
    '''Returns the data from n_results amount of results.'''
 
    accommodations_urls = list()
    accommodations_data = list()
 
    for accomodation_title in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sr-hotel__title'):
        accommodations_urls.append(accomodation_title.find_element_by_class_name(
            'hotel_name_link').get_attribute('href'))

    for url in range(0, n_results):
        if url == n_results:
            break
        url_data = scrape_accommodation_data(driver, accommodations_urls[url])
        accommodations_data.append(url_data)
    
    return accommodations_data
```

**EDIT**

I have added some more code to clarify my input and output. Again, I mostly just used code from the GoTrained tutorial and added some code of my own. How I understand it: the scraper first collects all URLs and then scrapes the info of the individual pages one by one. I need to add the pagination loop in that first part – I think.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    try:
        driver = prepare_driver(domain)
        fill_form(driver, 'Waterberg, South Africa') # my search argument
        accommodations_data = scrape_results(driver, 25) # 25 is the maximum of results, higher makes the scraper crash due to the pagination problem
        accommodations_data = json.dumps(accommodations_data, indent=4)
        with open('booking_data.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(accommodations_data)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Below is the JSON output for one search result.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Lodge Entabeni Safari Conservancy",
        "score": "8.4",
        "no_reviews": "41",
        "location": "Vosdal Plaas, R520 Marken Road, 0510 Golders Green, South Africa",
        "room_types": [
            "Tented Chalet - Wildside Safari Camp with 1 game drive",
            "Double or Twin Room - Hanglip Mountain Lodge with 1 game drive",
            "Tented Family Room - Wildside Safari Camp with 1 game drive"
        ],
        "room_prices": [
            "\u20ac 480",
            "\u20ac 214",
            "\u20ac 650",
            "\u20ac 290",
            "\u20ac 693"
        ],
        "popular_facilities": [
            "1 swimming pool",
            "Bar",
            "Very Good Breakfast"
        ]
    },
    
    ...
]
```

Comment: Can you show some input data and the result you're getting?

Comment: I have edited my post with some more code!

Comment: I'd either append the list out of the scrape method and put a loop inside main which clicks the next button or just append them all inside the scrape and loop there while reinitializing to 0 after page click.